# Ordenação de query - sql server

Tags: sql-server, query, classificação

Preciso ordenar minha query para que a coluna "NomeCentroConsolidacao" fique de acordo com a lógica aplicada na coluna "TodosOsNiveis" alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

```
            WITH CentroNiveis AS (
                        SELECT cen.Id, 
                               cen.IdCentroPai, 
                               cen.Nome,
                               CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), cen.Nome) AS TodosOsNiveis, 
                               cen.IdCliente,
                               cen.Tipo,
                               1 AS Nivel, 
                               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cen.Nome, cen.Id, cen.IdCentroPai) AS Ordem
                          FROM CentroConsolidacao cen
                         WHERE cen.IdCentroPai IS NULL
                           AND cen.Status = 'Ativo'  AND cen.IdCliente = '1'  AND cen.Tipo = 'Despesa' 

                         UNION ALL

                         SELECT cc.Id, 
                                cc.IdCentroPai, 
                                cc.Nome, 
                                CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), cn.TodosOsNiveis + ' - ' + cc.Nome) AS TodosOsNiveis, 
                                cc.IdCliente,
                                cc.Tipo,
                                Nivel+1,
                                Ordem
                           FROM CentroConsolidacao cc
                     INNER JOIN CentroNiveis cn ON cc.IdCentroPai = cn.Id
                          WHERE cc.Status = 'Ativo'
                                 )
        SELECT 
               CEN.Id AS IdCentroConsolidacao, 
               CEN.IdCentroPai AS IdCentroPai,

               CASE WHEN CEN.Nivel = 1 THEN CEN.Nome ELSE REPLICATE('          ' , CEN.Nivel-1) + CEN.Nome END AS NomeCentroConsolidacao, 
               CEN.TodosOsNiveis,

               CEN.Nivel,

               CASE WHEN CON.Id IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CON.Id END AS IdConta,
               CASE WHEN CON.Nome IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CON.Nome END AS NomeConta ,

               SUM(ABS(rat.Credito - rat.Debito)) OVER(PARTITION BY cen.Id ORDER BY cen.Id) AS TotalCentro,
               SUM(ABS(rat.Credito - rat.Debito)) OVER(PARTITION BY con.Id ORDER BY con.Id) AS TotalConta

          FROM CentroNiveis CEN
     LEFT JOIN Conta CON ON CEN.Id = CON.IdCentroConsolidacao
     LEFT JOIN Rateio rat ON rat.IdConta = con.Id
     LEFT JOIN Lancamento lanc ON lanc.Id = rat.IdLancamento

    WHERE 1=1  
      AND lanc.Status = 'Real' 
      AND lanc.Aprovado = 'Sim'  
      AND lanc.Data >= '2015-01-01'  
      AND lanc.Data <= '2015-12-31'  
      AND lanc.IdCliente = 1  
      AND lanc.Tipo IN ( 'Lançamento' , 'Transferência' )  
      AND cen.Tipo = 'Despesa'  
      AND lanc.IdFonte IN(1)  
      AND lanc.Status = 'Real' 
      AND lanc.Aprovado = 'Sim' 

       OR CEN.Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT c1.Id AS IdCentro
                       FROM CentroConsolidacao c1 
                 INNER JOIN CentroConsolidacao c2 ON c1.Id = c2.IdCentroPai OR c2.Id = c1.IdCentroPai
                      WHERE c1.IdCliente = 1)

       OR CEN.Nivel > 1

 GROUP BY
          CEN.Id, 
          CEN.IdCentroPai, 
          CEN.TodosOsNiveis,
          CON.Id,
          CON.Nome,

          CEN.Ordem, 
          CEN.Nivel, 
          CEN.Nome,

          RAT.Credito, 
          RAT.Debito

 ORDER BY CEN.Ordem, CEN.Nivel, CEN.Nome, CON.Nome
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Alguém tem alguma sugestão? Qualquer informação será útil.

Comment: Podes colocar um exemplo de como seria o output desejado?

Answer (score 1):

Você só precisa substituir os seguintes trechos de sua query:

Substitua

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), cn.TodosOsNiveis + ' - ' + cc.Nome) AS TodosOsNiveis,
```

por

```
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), cn.TodosOsNiveis + ' - ' + cc.Nome)), 0, CHARINDEX(' - ', REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), cn.TodosOsNiveis + ' - ' + cc.Nome))))) AS TodosOsNiveis,
```

e substitua

```
CEN.TodosOsNiveis,
```

por

```
CASE WHEN CEN.Nivel = 1 THEN CEN.TodosOsNiveis ELSE REPLICATE('          ' , CEN.Nivel-1) + CEN.TodosOsNiveis END AS TodosOsNiveis,
```

Seu código ficará da seguinte maneira:

```
            WITH CentroNiveis AS (
                        SELECT cen.Id, 
                               cen.IdCentroPai, 
                               cen.Nome,
                               CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), cen.Nome) AS TodosOsNiveis, 
                               cen.IdCliente,
                               cen.Tipo,
                               1 AS Nivel, 
                               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cen.Nome, cen.Id, cen.IdCentroPai) AS Ordem
                          FROM CentroConsolidacao cen
                         WHERE cen.IdCentroPai IS NULL
                           AND cen.Status = 'Ativo'  AND cen.IdCliente = '1'  AND cen.Tipo = 'Despesa' 

                         UNION ALL

                         SELECT cc.Id, 
                                cc.IdCentroPai, 
                                cc.Nome, 
                                REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), cn.TodosOsNiveis + ' - ' + cc.Nome)), 0, CHARINDEX(' - ', REVERSE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), cn.TodosOsNiveis + ' - ' + cc.Nome))))) AS TodosOsNiveis, 
                                cc.IdCliente,
                                cc.Tipo,
                                Nivel+1,
                                Ordem
                           FROM CentroConsolidacao cc
                     INNER JOIN CentroNiveis cn ON cc.IdCentroPai = cn.Id
                          WHERE cc.Status = 'Ativo'
                                 )
        SELECT 
               CEN.Id AS IdCentroConsolidacao, 
               CEN.IdCentroPai AS IdCentroPai,

               CASE WHEN CEN.Nivel = 1 THEN CEN.Nome ELSE REPLICATE('          ' , CEN.Nivel-1) + CEN.Nome END AS NomeCentroConsolidacao, 
               CASE WHEN CEN.Nivel = 1 THEN CEN.TodosOsNiveis ELSE REPLICATE('          ' , CEN.Nivel-1) + CEN.TodosOsNiveis END AS TodosOsNiveis,

               CEN.Nivel,

               CASE WHEN CON.Id IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CON.Id END AS IdConta,
               CASE WHEN CON.Nome IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CON.Nome END AS NomeConta ,

               SUM(ABS(rat.Credito - rat.Debito)) OVER(PARTITION BY cen.Id ORDER BY cen.Id) AS TotalCentro,
               SUM(ABS(rat.Credito - rat.Debito)) OVER(PARTITION BY con.Id ORDER BY con.Id) AS TotalConta

          FROM CentroNiveis CEN
     LEFT JOIN Conta CON ON CEN.Id = CON.IdCentroConsolidacao
     LEFT JOIN Rateio rat ON rat.IdConta = con.Id
     LEFT JOIN Lancamento lanc ON lanc.Id = rat.IdLancamento

    WHERE 1=1  
      AND lanc.Status = 'Real' 
      AND lanc.Aprovado = 'Sim'  
      AND lanc.Data >= '2015-01-01'  
      AND lanc.Data <= '2015-12-31'  
      AND lanc.IdCliente = 1  
      AND lanc.Tipo IN ( 'Lançamento' , 'Transferência' )  
      AND cen.Tipo = 'Despesa'  
      AND lanc.IdFonte IN(1)  
      AND lanc.Status = 'Real' 
      AND lanc.Aprovado = 'Sim' 

       OR CEN.Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT c1.Id AS IdCentro
                       FROM CentroConsolidacao c1 
                 INNER JOIN CentroConsolidacao c2 ON c1.Id = c2.IdCentroPai OR c2.Id = c1.IdCentroPai
                      WHERE c1.IdCliente = 1)

       OR CEN.Nivel > 1

 GROUP BY
          CEN.Id, 
          CEN.IdCentroPai, 
          CEN.TodosOsNiveis,
          CON.Id,
          CON.Nome,

          CEN.Ordem, 
          CEN.Nivel, 
          CEN.Nome,

          RAT.Credito, 
          RAT.Debito

 ORDER BY CEN.Ordem, CEN.Nivel, CEN.Nome, CON.Nome
```